# Is there a term other than "press conference" to refer to an event where a new product is unveiled?

Tags: word-request

["press conference" means](http://english.oxforddictionaries.com/press%20conference)

> an interview given to journalists by a prominent person in order to make an announcement or answer questions.
>
> The iPhone 4S was unveiled at Apple's "Let's Talk iPhone" event on October 4, 2011, on the Apple Campus in Cupertino, California.

I guess I could call that event a press conference, besides which, is there **any terms** to refer to that kind of event where a new product is unveiled in contrast to the other type of conference where experts answer some questions regarding to a specific field e.g. COVID-19?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are certainly right that we call it “press conference”, but I would rather call it **media event** or **press event**. At least that’s what Apple Inc. calls it when they refer to a product launch. **[Click here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Apple_Inc._media_events)**

[Media Event](https://www.definitions.net/definition/media+event):

> A media event is an event or activity that exists for the sole purpose of media publicity. Media events may center around a news announcement, a corporate anniversary, a press conference in response to a major media event, or planned events like speeches or demonstrations.

Answer (score 1):

> is there any terms to refer to that kind of event where a new product is unveiled

Product launch.